# Erro ao logar - PHP

Tags: php

Quando eu tento efetuar o Login, nada acontece e sou redirecionado novamente a página de login, o que posso fazer?

Código
    
    include_once("conexao.php");
    //O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
    if((isset($_POST['pnome'])) && (isset($_POST['psenha']))){

```
    echo 'entrou';

    $rm = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pnome']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['psenha']);

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM professor WHERE RM = '$rm' && Senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['professorRm'] = $resultado['RM'];
        $_SESSION['professorNome'] = $resultado['Nome'];
        $_SESSION['professorTurma'] = $resultado['Turma_ID'];
        $_SESSION['professorFoto'] = $resultado['Foto'];
        $_SESSION['professorSenha'] = $resultado['Senha'];
        $_SESSION['professorEmail'] = $resultado['Email'];
        $_SESSION['professorMateria'] = $resultado['Materia'];
        header("Location: perfilaluno.php");
    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
    }else{    
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Usuário ou senha Inválidos')</script>";
        header("Location:login.html");
    }
//O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
}else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Usuário ou senha Inválidos')</script>";
    header("Location:login.html");
}
```

?>

```
HTML
<form method="post" action="valida_prof.php">
<div align="center">
<font size="5">Insira o RM<br></font>
<input type="text" size="20" name="pnome"><br><br>
<font size="5">Insira a senha</font><br>
<input type="password" size="20"><br><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Logar">
</form>
```

Quando eu dou print("

```
"); print_r($_SESSION); print("
```

"); aparece isso:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente dar este comando e veja o que aparece print("<pre>"); print_r($_SESSION); print("</pre>"); este vai mostrar para você o que foi preenchido dentro da sua sessão.pois ele não mostra nada mesmo do jeuto que está seu código.

Comment: Certo, irei colocar na pergunta o resultado

Comment: E eu também adicionei o HTML, de onde vem as informações

Comment: Fiquei desconfiado do seguinte, você ao fazer login grava tudo na sessão professorXXXX, depois manda a pessoa para o perfil aluno, se lá não houver a sessão professorXXXX, você não vai conseguir recuperar os dados. Digo isso, pois tentei reproduzir seu código aqui, e deu tudo certinho, mas ele redireciona para perfilaluno.php, que não sei o que tem dentro. ajusta o nome das chaves das sessões nas duas páginas que deve dar certo.

Comment: O problema é que aqui ele não vai para o perfilaluno

Comment: Talvez, você esteja digitando uma informação que não está cadastrado no banco.